# Data driven plot names in data.table

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, data.table

This is a personal project to learn the syntax of the `data.table` package. I am trying to use the data values to create multiple graphs and label each based on the `by` group value. For example, given the following data:

```
# Generate dummy data
require(data.table)

set.seed(222)
DT = data.table(grp=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=10), 
 x = rnorm(30, mean=5, sd=1), 
 y = rnorm(30, mean=8, sd=1))

setkey(DT, grp)
```

The data consists of random x and y values for 3 groups (a, b, and c).  I can create a formatted plot of all values with the following code:

```
# Example of plotting all groups in one plot
require(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data=DT, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  aes(shape = factor(grp))+
  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(grp), shape = factor(grp)), size = 3) +
  labs(title = "Group: ALL")
p
```

This creates the following plot:
[image: Plot of all groups]

Instead I would like to create a separate plot for each `by` group, and change the plot title from “Group: ALL” to “Group: a”, “Group: b”, “Group: c”, etc.  The [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.0/topics/special-symbols) for data.table says:

> `.BY` is a list containing a length 1 vector for each item in `by`. This can be useful when by is not known in advance. The `by` variables are also available to `j` directly by name; useful for example for *titles of graphs* if `j` is a plot command, or to branch with `if()`

That being said, I do not understand how to use `.BY` or `.SD` to create separate plots for each group. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Rob, while you can do this with `data.table`, it really isn't what it's designed for.  `data.table` operates on subsets of itself, and then re-assembes a `data.table` with the result.  What you want is to have `data.table` cause side effects (produce graphs) for each group.  Again, you can do this with `data.table`, but a for loop or an lapply may make more sense.

Comment: Regarding your recommendation to use for-loops and lapply:  When/where would you use a for-loop or lapply versus data.table side effects?

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more, `data.table` might be better if only because it simplifies the splitting step.  Side effects are not the main reason to use it, but frankly it handles them just as well as other methods.  The main advantage of the other methods is that they are part of the base package, and my philosophy is that, unless an external package offers a clear advantage over base packages for a particular application, to use the base package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the `data.table` solution, though again, not what I would recommend:

```
make_plot <- function(dat, grp.name) {
  print(
    ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_point() + labs(title=paste0("Group: ", grp.name$grp))
  )
  NULL
}    
DT[, make_plot(.SD, .BY), by=grp]
```

What you really should do for this particular application is what @dmartin recommends.  At least, that's what I would do.

Comment: Perfect Brodie.  I agree there are alternatives (eg: faceting in ggplot) but I really was looking to better understand ".SD" and ".BY".  Thanks!

Comment: +1: I would be curious if this offered any speed advantages. I would guess that it does not, reasoning that this probably works mostly by virtue of data.tables inheriting from data.frame class.

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat It should be faster because the `split` `data.table` executes gets allocated to the same memory location (i.e. it iterates through each piece of the original re-using the same memory chunk for each piece), but here most of the execution time will probably be on the side effects side so I imagine it doesn't really matter.

Comment: ohh it's the `print` method that launches the plot. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using data.table, you could use facet_grid in ggplot with the labeller argument:

```
p <- ggplot(data=DT, aes(x = x, y = y)) + aes(shape = factor(grp)) +
     geom_point(aes(colour = factor(grp), shape = factor(grp)), size = 3) + 
     facet_grid(. ~ grp, labeller = label_both)
```

See the [ggplot documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_grid.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks dmartin.  I especially liked your detail of `. ~ grp` to add "grp: a" to the facet titles.

Comment: Or I should say, the `labeller = label_both` option.

Answer (score 2):

I see you already have a "facetting" option. I had done this

```
 p+facet_wrap('grp')
```

But this gives the same result:

```
 p+facet_wrap(~grp)
```

[image]